# Tikz / pgfplot: plot Alternating Sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

Is there any possibility to plot an alternating sequence?

Picture: Alternating sequence:

[image]

I don't need exacly the same output as above.

I tried the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  ymin = -1,
  ymax = 1,
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 4,
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=left]
    \addplot[domain=1:5, only marks]{(-1)^x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What I got is:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What is the value of `(-1)^{1.5}` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make sure that you're evaluating your function at the right points. If you've set the domain to `domain=1:5`, you should set the number of samples to `samples=5`, then you'll get points for `x=1,2,...,5`.

Alternatively, you can explicitly provide a list of sampling points using `samples at={1,...,5}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  ymin = -1,
  ymax = 1,
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 5,
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=left]
    \addplot[samples at={1,...,5}, only marks]{(-1)^x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```